# How to use Grep to replace square bracket with parenthesis

Tags: linux, sed

I've tried but it gives me back an error message.

`sed -i ‘s/[]/()/'`

`sed -i ‘s/\[]\/\()\/'`

All helps are appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Perhaps you have the escape wrong. Maybe it's like this. `sed -i ‘s/\[\]/\(\)/'`

Comment: If you prefer `s/` to the solution in the answer below, this works: `sed 's/\[/(/;s/\]/)/'` The *problem* is that square brackets have a special meaning in regular expressions. If you put them both in the same `s/` expression rather than two separate ones as I did it will only match a pair of square brackets with nothing between them. So `echo 'Hello [ How is it ] today []' | sed 's/\[\]/()/'` will output `Hello [ How is it ] today ()`

Answer (score 1):

You can try using

```
sed -i  'y/[]/()/'
```

**y/source/dest/**

Transliterate the characters in the pattern space which appear in source to the corresponding character in dest. *(taken from manual for the command)*

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting a working solution:

```
$ echo "text[ text ] text []" | sed '{s/\[/(/g;s/\]/)/g}'
text( text ) text ()
```